# SharePoint 2010 UserProfileService GetDirect Reports

Tags: user-profile-service

In the SharePoint 2010 User Profile Service API there is a method to get the manager of an employee by using the method
 `UserProfile.GetDirectReports()`.

I would like to do the same for these 2 properties:

- SPS-Dotted-line (Dotted-line Manager)
- Dotted-line-2 (Dotted Line Manager 2) *this is a custom property

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any of the user properties can be read or updated in code.  They took a few of the properties that they use frequently and put a dedicated method available to make it easier for them to get the value.

Something like this should work....

```
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(url) 
        {
            SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
            UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);

            UserProfile profile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(this.User);
            string dottedMgr = profile[propName].ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, just to make it clear my question is not about getting or updating a user profile. It's about given an employee I can get his/her manager using the UserProfile.GetDirectReports(); method provided by the User Profile Service API. Now, is there any way for me to do the same for other property.

Comment: There is no defined method that pulls that specific field, you would use the code above to read any of the other configured properties including the dotted line manager or your custom field.

Comment: Thanks again Mike, I have one last question.So I have to load all the user profile and check one by one. Wow, thats gonna hurt the page loading time very badly.

Do you have any technique or idea how to do the checking without hurting the page loading so much.

Comment: The GetUserProfile() method loads the profile xml for a single user.  That should not take a long time unless you have significant data stored in there.  The call should be sub-second.